# Client not receiving the response from Servlet

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am a beginner in Client Server application and developing very basic one with Java Servlet on Server side and JavaScript on client side.
I am using POST request of AJAX on the client side (index.html) like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $.post("/Serve",
      {
        name: "Donald Duck",
        city: "Duckburg"
      },
      function(data, status) {
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
      }
    );
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Send an HTTP POST request to a page and get the result back</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I am using GlassFish ver 4.1 and the Servlet code (myServe.java) looks like this:

```
public class MyServe extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.print("HI");
    }

}
```

Ideally the response should go to data variable in AJAX function and it should display that on button click, but the alert screen just displays the JS code again:
[image]

Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?
Also web.xml file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyServe</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.MyServe</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyServe</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Serve</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: @KrutikJayswal Sorry Can you please elaborate your question. You are asking about Web App?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajax request is going to wrong controller please make some correction into ajax request by remove `/` from `Serve`

```
      $("button").click(function(){
        $.post("Serve",
          {
            name: "Donald Duck",
            city: "Duckburg"
          },
          function(data, status) {
            alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
          }
        );
```

I think it will help you.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks :). Can you tell me why is this happening, because afaik we should provide relative path

Comment: @Enigma when register Servlet into web.xml. it's url pattern should be relative to application context root. rather then your html file and Jsp which parrel with `WEB-INF` directory. it's also relative with context root of app.

Comment: Got it. Thnks a ton :)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with plain text responses, and xml is recommended, byt you may try this out

```
public class MyServe extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws IOException{
        response.setContentType("text/plain;charset=UTF-8");
        try(PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();){
        out.print("HI");}
    }
}
```

I don't know if the client(jquery) expect plain response(with or without header), but for xml types I mentioned, setting the content type is essential.

---

Also note that the client is calling `/Serve/` which is not `/Serve` where registered in `web.xml`

---

Try to call the servlet as full qualified name(like `http://[::1]/my_app/Serve`) rather than relative(`/Serve`). If the web-app has not registered as root context, then client will call `http:://[::1]/Serve` instead of actual/expected `http://[::1]/my_app/Serve`

Comment: Thanks for the edits, and I have tried that out, but still the problem persists. I think the plain text responses should be ok because i have seen examples regarding this. But I can be wrong

Comment: Check the edit dear, also what kinda of code you get from client? 404? you may also have a request by calling the full qualified servlet path as mentioned in edit. @Enigma

Comment: After your edit it is showing 404. And still not working